# High Pass Butterworth Filter on images in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, filtering, signal-processing

I need to implement a high pass Butterworth filter in MATLAB for the purposes of image filtering.  I have implemented one but it looks like it doesn't work.  Here is the code I have written.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

```
n=1;
d=50;
A=1.5;
im=imread('imagex.jpg');
h=size(im,1);
w=size(im,2);
[x y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor(w-1/2),-floor(h/2):floor(h-1/2));
hhp=(1./(d./(x.^2+y.^2).^0.5).^(2*n));
image_2Dfilter=fftshift(fft2(im));
Image_butterworth=image_2Dfilter;
imshow(Image_butterworth);
ifftshow(Image_butterworth);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For one thing, there is no such command called `ifftshow`.  Secondly, you aren't filtering anything.  All you're doing is visualizing the spectrum of the image.

In terms of visualizing the spectrum, how you're doing it right now is very dangerous.  For one thing, you are visualizing the coefficients at each spatial frequency component which is **complex-valued** in nature.  If you want to visualize the spectrum in a way that makes sense to most of us, it's better to take a look at either the **magnitude** or **phase**.  However, because this is a Butterworth filter, it's best to apply it to the magnitude of the filter.

You can find the magnitude of the spectrum by using the `abs` function.  Even when you do that, if you did `imshow` directly on the magnitude, you will get a visualization that is zero everywhere **except** for the middle.  This is because the DC component is so large and the rest of the spectrum is small in comparison.

Let me show you an example.  This is the cameraman image that is part of the image processing toolbox:

```
im = imread('cameraman.tif');
figure;
imshow(im);
```

[image]

Now, let's visualize the spectrum and ensuring that the DC component is in the centre of the image - you already did this with `fftshift`.  It's also a good idea to **cast the image to `double`** to ensure the best precision of data.  In addition, make sure you apply `abs` to find the magnitude:

```
fftim = fftshift(fft2(double(im)));
mag = abs(fftim);
figure;
imshow(mag, []);
```

[image]

As you can see, it's not very useful due to the reason that I mentioned.  A better way to visualize the spectrum of the image is usually to apply a **log** transformation to the spectrum.  This is also useful if you want to de-mean or remove the mean so that the dynamic range fits better for display.  In other words, you would add 1 to the magnitude, then apply a logarithm to the magnitude so that higher values can taper off.  It doesn't matter which base you use, so I'll just use the natural logarithm which is encapsulated by the `log` command:

```
figure;
imshow(log(1 + mag), []);
```

[image]

Now that's **much** better.  Now we'll get onto your filtering mechanism.  Your Butterworth filter is slightly incorrect.  The `meshgrid` of coordinates is slightly wrong.  The `-1` operation that's at the ending interval needs to go outside:

```
[x y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor(w/2)-1,-floor(h/2):floor(h/2)-1);
```

Remember, you are defining a symmetric interval about the centre of the image, and what you had originally wasn't correct.  I'd also like to mention that this looks like a **high-pass filter**, so the output should look like an edge detection.  In addition, the definition of the Butterworth high pass filter is incorrect.  The correct definition of the filter in frequency domain is:

[image]

`D(u,v)` is the distance from the centre of the image in frequency domain, `Do` is the cutoff distance while `B` is a controlling scale factor controlling what the desired gain would be at the cutoff distance.  `n` is the order of the filter.  `Do` in your case is `d = 50`.  In practice, `B = sqrt(2) - 1` so that at the cutoff distance of `Do`, `D(u,v) = 1 / sqrt(2) = 0.707`, which is the 3 dB cutoff frequency mostly seen in electronics circuit filters.  Sometimes you'll see `B` being set to 1 for simplicity, but it's common to set this to `B = sqrt(2) - 1`.

However, your current code isn't doing any filtering.  To filter in the frequency domain, you simply multiply the spectrum of the image with the spectrum of the filter itself.  This is equivalent to convolution in the spatial domain.  Once you do that, you simply undo the `fftshift` that was performed on the image, take the inverse FFT and then eliminate any imaginary components that are due to numerical imprecision.  Also, let's cast to `uint8` to make sure that we respect the original image type.

That can be done like so:

```
%// Your code with meshgrid fix
n=1;
d=50;
h=size(im,1);
w=size(im,2);
fftim = fftshift(fft2(double(im)));
[x y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor(w/2)-1,-floor(h/2):floor(h/2)-1);
%hhp=(1./(d./(x.^2+y.^2).^0.5).^(2*n));

%%%%%%// New code
B = sqrt(2) - 1; %// Define B
D = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2); %// Define distance to centre
hhp = 1 ./ (1 + B * ((d ./ D).^(2 * n)));
out_spec_centre = fftim .* hhp;

%// Uncentre spectrum
out_spec = ifftshift(out_spec_centre);

%// Inverse FFT, get real components, and cast
out = uint8(real(ifft2(out_spec)));

%// Show image
imshow(out);
```

If you want to see what the filtered spectrum looks like, just do this:

```
figure;
imshow(log(1 + abs(out_spec_centre)), []);
```

We get:

[image]

This makes sense.  You see that in the middle of the spectrum, it's slightly darker in comparison to the outer edges of the spectrum.  That's because with the high-pass Butterworth filter, you are amplifying the higher frequency terms and it gets visualized to be a higher intensity.

Now, `out` contains your filtered image, and we finally get this:

[image]

That looks like a fine result!  However, naively casting the image to `uint8` truncates any negative values to 0 and any positive values greater than 255 to 255.  Because this is an edge detection, you want to detect both the negative and positive transitions... so a good idea would be to **normalize** the output so that it ranges from `[0,1]`, and then cast with `uint8` after you multiply by 255.  This way, no changes in the image get visualized to gray, negative changes get visualized as dark and positive changes get visualized as white.... so you'd do something like this:

```
%// Your code with meshgrid fix
n=1;
d=50;
h=size(im,1);
w=size(im,2);
fftim = fftshift(fft2(double(im)));
[x y]=meshgrid(-floor(w/2):floor(w/2)-1,-floor(h/2):floor(h/2)-1);
%hhp=(1./(d./(x.^2+y.^2).^0.5).^(2*n));

%%%%%%// New code
B = sqrt(2) - 1; %// Define B
D = sqrt(x.^2 + y.^2); %// Define distance to centre
hhp = 1 ./ (1 + B * ((d ./ D).^(2 * n)));
out_spec_centre = fftim .* hhp;

%// Uncentre spectrum
out_spec = ifftshift(out_spec_centre);

%// Inverse FFT, get real components
out = real(ifft2(out_spec));

%// Normalize and cast
out = (out - min(out(:))) / (max(out(:)) - min(out(:)));
out = uint8(255*out);

%// Show image
imshow(out);
```

We get this:

[image]

Comment: "A better way to visualize the spectrum of the image is usually to apply a log transformation to the spectrum." Or to demean the image. Also, you talk about numerical imprecisions; never EVER compute square roots like this `D = (x.^2 + y.^2).^(0.5);`, use the function `sqrt` instead.

Comment: @Sheljohn Thanks for your suggestions.  I'll edit my post accordingly.  I did a quick read and noticed that if we know for sure that we want to find the square root, use the tuned `sqrt()` function.  Otherwise, this will call the generic power function and won't be as precise as use `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you should work a little bit diferent

```
n=1;
D0=50; % change the name for d0, d is usuaally the (u²+v²)⁽1/2)

A=1.5; % normally the amplitude is 1

im=imread('cameraman.jpg');

[M,N]=size(im); % is easy to get the h and w like this

% compute the 2d fourier transform in order to multiply

F=fft2(double(im));

% compute your filter and do the meshgrid for your matrix but it is M*n, and get only the real part

u=0:(M-1);
v=0:(N-1);

idx=find(u>M/2);
u(idx)=u(idx)-M;
idy=find(v>N/2);
v(idy)=v(idy)-N;
[V,U]=meshgrid(v,u);
D=sqrt(U.^2+V.^2);
H =A * (1./(1 + (D0./D).^(2*n)));

% multiply element by element

G=H.*F;
g=real(ifft2(double(G)));
subplot(1,2,1); imshow(im); title('Input image');
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(g,[ ]); title('filtered image');
```

Comment: is this formula of high-pass filter correct? the other answer seems to have a different formula.