# How can I implement a low-pass Butterworth filter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, lowpass-filter, butterworth

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279157/159072), I know how to create a High-pass Butterworth filter.

From [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTrRDpBzrto&list=PLEo-jHOqGNyUWoCSD3l3V-FjX9PnHvx5n&index=24), I know that, **`lowpasskernel = 1 - highpasskernel`**.

So, I created the following Low-pass Butterworth Filter,

```
function [out, kernel] = butterworth_lp(I, Dl, n)
    height = size(I, 1);
    width  = size(I, 2);

    [u, v] = meshgrid(-floor(width/2):floor(width/2)-1,-floor(height/2):floor(height/2)-1);

    % lp_kernel = 1 - hp_kernel
    kernel = 1 - butter_hp_kernel(u, v, Dl, n);

    % fft the image
    I_fft_shifted = fftshift(fft2(double(I)));

    % apply lowpass filter
    I_fft_shift_filtered = I_fft_shifted .* kernel;

    % inverse FFT, get real components
    out = real(ifft2(ifftshift(I_fft_shift_filtered)));

    % normalize and cast
    out = (out - min(out(:))) / (max(out(:)) - min(out(:)));
    out = uint8(255*out);

function k = butter_hp_kernel(u, v, Dh, n)
    uv =  u.^2+v.^2;
    D = sqrt(uv);
    frac = Dh./D;
    p = 2*n;
    denom =  frac.^p;
    k = 1./denom;
```

*Output*

[image]

This isn't a low-pass filter output.

So, **what is the issue with my code?**

Comment: Where are you doing 1 - anything?

Comment: Ok. But what code did you run to get that image? The fact you had to edit it just now doesn't fill me with confidence...

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth, both of your doubts addressed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Okay. I have solved the problem by following the [following formula (Page #8/48)](http://mstrzel.eletel.p.lodz.pl/mstrzel/pattern_rec/filtering.pdf),

[image]

*Output*

[image]

*Source Code*

**butter_lp_kernel.m**

```
function f = butter_lp_f(u, v, Dl, n)
    uv = u.^2+v.^2;
    Duv = sqrt(uv);
    frac = Duv./Dl;
    denom = frac.^(2*n);
    f = 1./(1.+denom);

function k = butter_lp_kernel(I, Dl, n) 
    Height = size(I,1); 
    Width = size(I,2); 

    [u, v] = meshgrid( ...
                    -floor(Width/2) :floor(Width-1)/2, ...
                    -floor(Height/2): floor(Height-1)/2 ...
                 ); 

    k = butter_lp_f(u, v, Dl, n);
```

**ifftshow.m**

```
function out = ifftshow(f)
    f1 = abs(f);
    fm = max(f1(:));
    out = f1/fm;
end
```

**butterworth_lpf.m**

```
function [out1, out2] = butterworth_lpf(I, Dl, n)

    Kernel = butter_lp_kernel(I, Dl, n);

    I_ffted_shifted = fftshift(fft2(I));

    I_ffted_shifted_filtered = I_ffted_shifted.*Kernel;

    out1 = ifftshow(ifft2(I_ffted_shifted_filtered));

    out2 = ifft2(ifftshift(I_ffted_shifted_filtered));
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You didn't correctly copy the formula in the high pass filter:

```
 uv =  u.^2+v.^2;
 D = uv.^0.5;
 frac = Dh./D;
 p = 2*n;
 denom =  frac.^p;
 k = 1./(1+denom); --> you forgot the "1+"
```

New output:

[image]

Comment: No, the meshgrid call is correct. The formula is also probably not correct which is the main culprit. To give a better answer, provide the correct implementation of the filter. This answer is currently not helpful in this state.

Comment: True, in the movie it's different but it doesn't matter. It's the formula that's wrong. I'll edit it.

Comment: Also, to get the most out of this and a vote from me, actually show an example filtered image. It'll really show that it's the formula that's wrong.