# How can I implement a high-pass Butterworth filter in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, highpass-filter, butterworth

According to Page#14 of [this link](http://mstrzel.eletel.p.lodz.pl/mstrzel/pattern_rec/filtering.pdf), the equation for a high-pass Butterworth filter is,

[image]

And, according to Page#17, the output should be something like the following,

[image]

Now, I have looked at this [answer in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30279157/159072), and has written the following Matlab code using the formula given in the linked pdf document.

The output looks different than that of the one given above.

[image]

**What is the possible problem in my source code?**

---

*Source Code*

**main.m**

```
clear_all();

I = gray_imread('cameraman.png');

n = 1;
Dh = 10;

[J, Kernel] = butterworth_hp(I, Dh, n);

imshowpair(I, J, 'montage');
```

**butterworth_hp.m**

```
function [out, kernel] = butterworth_hp(I, Dh, n)
height = size(I, 1);
width = size(I, 2);

I_fft_shifted = fftshift(fft2(double(I)));

[u, v] = meshgrid(-floor(width/2):floor(width/2)-1,-floor(height/2):floor(height/2)-1);
kernel = butter_hp_kernel(u, v, Dh, n);

I_fft_shift_filtered = I_fft_shifted .* kernel;

out = real(ifft2(ifftshift(I_fft_shift_filtered)));

out = (out - min(out(:))) / (max(out(:)) - min(out(:)));
out = uint8(255*out);


function k = butter_hp_kernel(u, v, D0, n)
uv =  u.^2+v.^2;
Duv = uv.^0.5;
frac = D0./Duv;
p = 2*n;
denom =  frac.^p;
A = 0.414;
k = 1./(1+A*denom);
```

Comment: @beaker, that answer is incorrect. I also provided the links.

Comment: I have corrected the Butterworth HPF equation in my post that you linked and explained why the factor of `sqrt(2) - 1` is required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.

[image]

The key to solving this problem was the function `ifftshow()`.

---

*Source Code*

**main.m**

```
clear_all();
I = gray_imread('cameraman.png');
Dh = 10;
n = 1;
[J, K] = butterworth_hpf(I, Dh, n);

imshowpair(I, K, 'montage');
%draw_multiple_images({I, J, K});
```

**ifftshow.m**

```
function out = ifftshow(f)
    f1 = abs(f);
    fm = max(f1(:));
    out = f1/fm;
end
```

**butter_hp_kernel.m**

```
function k = butter_hp_kernel(I, Dh, n) 
    Height = size(I,1); 
    Width = size(I,2); 

    [u, v] = meshgrid( ...
                    -floor(Width/2) :floor(Width-1)/2, ...
                    -floor(Height/2): floor(Height-1)/2 ...
                 ); 

    k = butter_hp_f(u, v, Dh, n);

function f = butter_hp_f(u, v, Dh, n)
    uv = u.^2+v.^2;
    Duv = sqrt(uv);
    frac = Dh./Duv;
    %denom = frac.^(2*n);
    A=0.414; denom = A.*(frac.^(2*n));    
    f = 1./(1.+denom);
```

**butterworth_hpf.m**

```
function [out1, out2] = butterworth_hpf(I, Dh, n)

    Kernel = butter_hp_kernel(I, Dh, n);

    I_ffted_shifted = fftshift(fft2(I));

    I_ffted_shifted_filtered = I_ffted_shifted.*Kernel;

    out1 = ifftshow(ifft2(I_ffted_shifted_filtered));

    out2 = ifft2(ifftshift(I_ffted_shifted_filtered));
end
```